# how to resolve laravel fileinfo extension problem?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php, fileinfo

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.34.2] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.23.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.14.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.23.0] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.23.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.14.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.23.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.34.2].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files\php-8.1.26-Win32-vs16-x64\php.ini
```

how to solve this problem?
it is mentioned that the minimum requirement of thr php version is 7.2 but i have 8.1 and it isn't working.
problem with my fileinfo extention. i have already enabled it by removing the semi-colens ":" but still it's not working.

how to resolve this

Comment: "_To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:_" Did you do that?

Comment: "_i have already enabled it_" Did you restart your webserver after making changes to your `php.ini`? Does it show as enabled on a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` page?

Comment: Restart  php and check your packages dependencies and compatibility with laravel 10.10.x